# Proving a theorem about parser combinators

Tags: isabelle

I've written some simple parser combinators (without backtracking etc.). Here are the important definitions for my problem.

```
type_synonym ('a, 's) parser = "'s list ⇒ ('a * 's list) option"

definition sequenceP :: "('a, 's) parser
                       ⇒ ('b, 's) parser
                       ⇒ ('b, 's) parser" (infixl ">>P" 60) where
  "sequenceP p q ≡ λ i . 
    (case p i of
        None ⇒ None
      | Some v ⇒ q (snd v))"

definition consumerP :: "('a, 's) parser ⇒ bool" where
  "consumerP p ≡ (∀ i . (case p i of 
    None ⇒ True |
    Some v ⇒ length (snd v) ≤ length i))"
```

I do want to proof the following lemma.

```
lemma consumerPI: "consumerP p ⟹ consumerP q ⟹ consumerP (p >>P q)"
apply (unfold sequenceP_def)
apply (simp (no_asm) add:consumerP_def)
apply clarsimp
apply (case_tac "case p i of None ⇒ None | Some v ⇒ q (snd v)")
apply simp
apply clarsimp
apply (case_tac "p i")
apply simp
apply clarsimp
apply (unfold consumerP_def)
```

I arrive at this proof state, at which I fail to continue.

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀i a b aa ba.
       ⟦∀i. case p i of None ⇒ True | Some v ⇒ length (snd v) ≤ length i;
        ∀i. case q i of None ⇒ True | Some v ⇒ length (snd v) ≤ length i; q ba = Some (a, b); p i = Some (aa, ba)⟧
       ⟹ length b ≤ length i
```

Can anybody give me a tip how to solve this goal?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just checking: Did you read the goal careful, and are you confident that it is indeed a provable theorem?
Also, have you tried running `sledgehammer` I would not be surprised if that could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you just want to prove the lemma, without further insight, then

```
lemma consumerPI: "consumerP p ⟹ consumerP q ⟹ consumerP (p >>P q)"
by (smt consumerP_def le_trans option.case_eq_if sequenceP_def)
```

does the job.

If you want to have insight, you want to go for a structured proof. First identify some useful lemmas about `consumerP`, and then write a Isar proof that details the necessary steps.

```
lemma consumerPI[intro!]:
  assumes "⋀ i x r . p i = Some (x,r) ⟹ length r ≤ length i"
  shows "consumerP p"
 unfolding consumerP_def by (auto split: option.split elim: assms)

lemma consumerPE[elim, consumes 1]:
  assumes "consumerP p"
  assumes "p i = Some (x,r)"
  shows "length r ≤ length i"
  using assms by (auto simp add: consumerP_def split: option.split_asm)

lemma consumerP_sequencePI: "consumerP p ⟹ consumerP q ⟹ consumerP (p >>P q)"
proof-
  assume "consumerP p"
  assume "consumerP q"
  show "consumerP (p >>P q)"
  proof(rule consumerPI)
    fix i x r
    assume "(p >>P q) i = Some (x, r)"
    then obtain x' r' where "p i = Some (x', r')" and "q r' = Some (x,r)"
      by (auto simp add: sequenceP_def split:option.split_asm)

    from `consumerP q` and `q r' = Some (x, r)`
    have "length r ≤ length r'" by (rule consumerPE)
    also
    from `consumerP p` and `p i = Some (x', r')`
    have "length r' ≤ length i" by (rule consumerPE)
    finally
    show "length r ≤ length i".
  qed
qed
```

In fact, for this definition you can very nicely use the `inductive` command, and get intro and elim rules for free:

```
inductive consumerP where
  consumerPI: "(⋀ i x r . p i = Some (x,r) ⟹ length r ≤ length i) ⟹ consumerP p"
```

In the above proof, you can replace `by (rule consumerPE)` by `by cases` and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first proof looks like it was acquired via sledgehammer? How did you do this because for me sledgehammer timed out.

Comment: Nothing special, just typed `sledgehammer` and waited. Do you get it if you increase the timeout?

Comment: Yes when setting the timeout to 80s I do get a result.

Comment: Can you recommend some timeout for which experience has shown that if sledgehammer hasn't found a proof it won't find any in a reasonable time?

Comment: I only work with the default, but I use the `sledgehammer` command and not the panel (which might have a shorter timeout). Also of course it depends on your machine.